# GLFW: Compilation errors C++

Tags: c++, opengl, compiler-errors, glfw

I just finished installing GLFW for C++ in order to work with OpenGL, and when I run the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glfw.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int running = GL_TRUE;

    if (!glfwInit())
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    if (!glfwOpenWindow(300, 300, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, GLFW_WINDOW))
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (running)
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        glClearColor(rand() % 255 + 1, rand() % 255 + 1, rand() % 255 + 1, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers();

        running = !glfwGetKey(GLFW_KEY_ESC) && glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

, it throws the following error:

```
Error:
build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o: In function `main':
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\NetBeans Workspace\OpenGL_Testing/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `glfwInit'
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\NetBeans Workspace\OpenGL_Testing/main.cpp:11: undefined reference to `glfwOpenWindow'
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\NetBeans Workspace\OpenGL_Testing/main.cpp:13: undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\NetBeans Workspace\OpenGL_Testing/main.cpp:22: undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\NetBeans Workspace\OpenGL_Testing/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\NetBeans Workspace\OpenGL_Testing/main.cpp:24: undefined reference to `glfwGetWindowParam'
C:\Users\User\Dropbox\NetBeans Workspace\OpenGL_Testing/main.cpp:27: undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
```

And yes, I have linked opengl32.lib into my project.

Comment: I am not using codeblocks though. That environment specifically allows the creation of a GLFW project unlike NetBeans (and I'd rather not switch IDEs).  Unless Netbeans has a way to do this?

Comment: The same things apply though, OpenGL is not GLFW - linking opengl32.lib is not enough.

Comment: Then what do I link besides that? I have already gone through that entire process.  Is there another lib file I have to directly link to with my project?

Comment: GLFW.lib, available from the GLFW sourceforge site, easily found via google or in the first answer in the question that I linked you to.

Comment: I have already tried that.  It gives me a much larger error.  I guess I should mention I am using minGW as well.  But ya, whenever I try using that lib it breaks the code even more.

Comment: Well then you need the `mingw` libs - this is exactly what the first answer in the question I linked to (hint hint) explains in detail (libglfw.a and libglfwdll.a). You will also need an opengl32 library that works with minGW, but I assume you took care of that already?!

Comment: Lol sorry if I've been coming off as a jerk, but I already threw libglfw.a and libglfwdll.a into the lib folder of mingw and put the dll into the System32 folder.  I also linked the opengl32 into my project which works (I tested it with freeGLUT).  It is just when I add the GLFW.lib, I get worse errors than before.

Comment: Hmmm. I'm out of ideas in that case, sorry. (You shouldn't need GLFW.lib with mingw, just the .a files.)

Comment: Well alright. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Show your compile command line.